# How to redirect a verbose console to TextBox in C# without slowing down the application

Tags: c#, textbox, console

I am redirecting my console to a `TextBox` using the following setup :

```cs
public partial class WindowMain : Window
{
    public WindowMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
        TextWriter writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(consoleTextBox);
        Console.SetOut(writer);
    }
}
```

with class `TextBoxStreamWriter` :

```cs
public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output = null;

    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        base.Write(value);
        _output.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString());
        })
        );
    }
}
```

This is working. When I call `Console.Write` in my application my TextBox is appended correctly. The problem is I am feeding the console with very large data continuously (output of a very verbose batch launched via a `Process` calling `cmd.exe`)

```cs
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    }
};
```

The issue here is that this is slowing down the whole application (particularly threads that I launch during the feeding). My idea is to manually control the frequency of writing. However I feel this is a common issue and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I am sure this is possible with the Reactive Extensions. Unfortunatelly, I don't have experience with them, so I can't provide an actual example. But you could start looking in that direction if you don't get any answer here.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up not using the console anymore. My application has no need for a console indeed.

```cs
process.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        consoleTextBox.AppendText(e.Data);
    }
};
```

My solution was more complex than the piece of code above since I use threads (which is what confused my in the first place, making me think using the console was smart).